# Requesting help interpreting perf report output

Tags: 18.04, kernel, performance, mtp, fuse

I'm trying to troubleshoot a long delay between file transfers over usb from android phone mounted using jmtpfs on ubuntu server 18.04. This is an extension of question: "[Stat system call takes a rediculously long time to complete on android mounted via jmtpfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138209/stat-system-call-takes-a-rediculously-long-time-to-complete-on-android-mounted)".

I've recorded the perf output of command:

```
sudo perf record -g cp -pv /home/odwongm/phone/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20140426_174534.jpg /home/odwongm/phone/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20140426_174607.jpg /home/odwongm/phone_rsync/
```

I'm way out of my depth here and have no idea how to interpret the results. I think the result shows that most of the samples taken are on: copy_user_generic_string.

> Samples: 44  of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 16619252
>   Children      Self  Command  Shared Object      Symbol
>   +   92.25%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
>   +   92.25%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] do_syscall_64
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       libc-2.27.so       [.] write 
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] sys_write
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] vfs_write
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __vfs_write
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] new_sync_write
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] ext4_file_write_iter
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __generic_file_write_iter
>   +   45.00%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] generic_perform_write
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       libc-2.27.so       [.] read
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] sys_read 
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] vfs_read 
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __vfs_read
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] new_sync_read
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] fuse_file_read_iter
>   +   28.06%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] generic_file_read_iter
>   +   24.79%    24.79%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] copy_user_generic_string
>   +   21.76%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] ext4_da_write_begin

I've also expanded some of the results, it's unclear to me what this all shows however.

> - 92.25%     0.00%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] do_syscall_64
>
>   - 15.66% do_syscall_64
>       sys_read
>       vfs_read
>       __vfs_read
>       new_sync_read
>       fuse_file_read_iter
>       generic_file_read_iter
>       copy_page_to_iter
>       copy_user_generic_string
>   - 9.13% do_syscall_64
>       sys_write
>       vfs_write
>       __vfs_write
>       new_sync_write
>       ext4_file_write_iter
>       __generic_file_write_iter
>       generic_perform_write
>       iov_iter_copy_from_user_atomic
>       copy_user_generic_string
> - 24.79%    24.79%  cp       [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] copy_user_generic_string
>
>   - 15.66% read
>       entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
>       do_syscall_64
>       sys_read
>       vfs_read
>       __vfs_read
>       new_sync_read
>       fuse_file_read_iter
>       generic_file_read_iter
>       copy_page_to_iter
>       copy_user_generic_string
>   - 9.13% 0x52d407016256000e
>       write
>       entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
>       do_syscall_64
>       sys_write
>       vfs_write
>       __vfs_write
>       new_sync_write
>       ext4_file_write_iter
>       __generic_file_write_iter
>       generic_perform_write
>       iov_iter_copy_from_user_atomic
>       copy_user_generic_string

Can anyone with expertise with perf tool shed some insights into these results?